# Create NSPersistentContainer without any persistent data

Tags: swift, core-data

I create a `NSPersistentContainer` like this:

```
static let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer =  {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyUselessApp")

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (nsPersistentStoreDescription, error) in
        guard let error = error else {
            // Everything went well
            return
        }

        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    })

    return container
}()
```

It loads all data/objects that are saved. Is it possible to create a `NSPersistentContainer` without any data, but still holds all the entities that I defined in `MyUselessApp.xcdatamodeld`?

I want to do this because I have a `UIViewController` with a `NSFetchResultController`, but everytime the `UIViewController` will be presented, the data needs to be refreshed (I can not cache anything). The current way I am doing it, is that I delete every object that the `NSPredicate` will return from the `NSFetchResultController`. That looks like a useless step to me. All my tableviews that contain dynamic data use NSFetchResultController and I prefer to keep using it this way.

Comment: Why would you save them in the first place then? You could have a context acting like a scratchpad and `reset()` (or discard/recreate) it every time you need to discard the managed objects you have created. Also, if you only need persistence in the runtime you could set the `NSInMemoryStoreType`.

Comment: @Alladinian without saving the delegate method's wont fire right?

Comment: If you are referring to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods (`controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` for example), my understanding is that they will be triggered. You could give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was the only thing I needed to do:

```
let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "InMemoryCoreDataContainer")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

lazy var mockPersistantContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "InMemoryCoreDataContainer", managedObjectModel: persistentContainer.managedObjectModel)
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

    description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
    description.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false // Make it simpler in test env

    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
        precondition( description.type == NSInMemoryStoreType )

        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Create an in-mem coordinator failed \(error)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()
```